# Can't boot from SATA but USB booting works. BIOS can't detect SATA hard drive

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop, asus

Problem:

1. can't booting trough sata port
2. booting only work with usb port (with hdd enclosure)
3. bios can't detect sata hard drive.
4. sata port only detect hard drive as mass storage, but not as booting device.

what i have tried and still not working:

1. unplug and then plug my hdd again
2. change my sata configuration (ahci and raid, no other choices)
3. reset bios to default
4. unplug all my laptop component and then plug it again (trying to unplug cmos battery but didn't found it so i just unplug all component)
5. Change my harddrive format (mbr and gpt)

it all works normal until i restart my laptop.

Comment: (of the 2nd set) #5 and #2 if changed to anything other than the mode the OS was installed originally automatically negates any truthfulness of the assertion "it all works normal until i restart my laptop". Simply put, it's impossible. (of the 1st set) your #2 is also impossible unless you have installed a Windows To Go. The normal Windows can't be installed in external drives.

Comment: I suggest you start by assuring all the pertinent UEFI settings are correct/optimal - UEFI mode only, the target drive as the in the BBS order (or similar depending on your firmware), disable Fast Boot... - and then reinstall Windows.

Comment: Maybe the sata data cable is bad

Comment: it work normal, i use it for my addition storage now. the problem is it won't detect any harddrive as booting device.